# PubNub Integration with Node js and IOS devices

Tags: node.js, pubnub

I need to setup communication between **Node.js** and **iOS** devices with **pubnub**.
Problem is that we have an ios app for restaurant,and need to track order(latitude and longitude) by the customer who placed the order through iOS.
After placing the order , picked-up by the deivery driver as we see in the ubercab app. So we need to track oder on google map.

Is there any requirement to call node.js services.

Please suggest me the right way how we communicate with Node.js services, Restaurant app and PUBNUB API.

Please  help!!!!

Comment: Use REST API https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer so everyone can communicate with your Node app via API

Comment: Hi Michelem,
Can you tell me what will be the flow of communication with ios app with nodejs services and pubnub.

Comment: iOS App and Pubnub  must have some king of REST API too, then you can call them from your Node.js or viceversa

Comment: There are four modules as Driver(iosApp),Customer(iosApp),Nodejs server,PubNub.if A customer placed an order then it will be accept by driver, after establishing communication betwwen customer and driver or order accept by driver to delivery then how they can get the push notification and update their location with Pubnub.

Comment: You need a developer.

Comment: Michelem, Can you tell me the flow regarding this ?

Answer (score 1):

There is set of SDK for different platforms to communicate with **PubNub** services available [here](http://www.pubnub.com/developers/).